# Does Java need closures?

Tags: java, closures

I've been reading a lot lately about the next release of Java possibly supporting [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).  I feel like I have a pretty firm grasp on what closures are, but I can't think of a solid example of how they would make an Object-Oriented language "better".  Can anyone give me a specific use-case where a closure would be needed (or even preferred)?

Answer (score 72):

As a Lisp programmer I would wish that the Java community understands the following difference: **functions as objects vs. closures**.

a) **functions can be named or anonymous**. But they can also be objects of themselves. This allows functions to be passed around as arguments, returned from functions or stored in data structures. This means that functions are first class objects in a programming language.

Anonymous functions don't add much to the language, they just allow you to write functions in a shorter way.

b) **A closure is a function plus a binding environment**. Closures can be passed *downwards* (as parameters) or returned *upwards* (as return values). This allows the function to refer to variables of its environment, even if the surrounding code is no longer active.

If you have **a)** in some language, then the question comes up what to do about **b)**? There are languages that have **a)**, but not **b)**. In the functional programming world **a)** (functions) and **b** (functions as closures) is nowadays the norm. Smalltalk had **a)** (*blocks* are anonymous functions) for a long time, but then some dialects of Smalltalk added support for **b)** (blocks as closures).

You can imagine that you get a slightly different programming model, if you add functions and closures to the language.

From a pragmatic view, the anonymous function adds some short notation, where you pass or invoke functions. That can be a good thing.

The closure (function plus binding) allows you for example to create a function that has access to some variables (for example to a counter value). Now you can store that function in an object, access it and invoke it. The context for the function object is now not only the objects it has access to, but also the variables it has access to via bindings. This is also useful, but you can see that variable bindings vs. access to object variables now is an issue: when should be something a *lexical* variable (that can be accessed in a closure) and when should it be a variable of some object (a *slot*). When should something be a closure or an object? You can use both in the similar ways. A usual programming exercise for students learning Scheme (a Lisp dialect) is to write a simple object system using closures.

The result is a more complicated programming language and a more complicated runtime model. Too complicated?

Comment: +2 if i could. This is the 'missing link' in discussions about java closures. Deserves a question of it's own, Rainer.

Comment: This is the best description of a closure that I have encountered. I understand now why the new closure implementation is being limited to local only. Danger Will Robinson, Danger!

Comment: +1 Now I understand why Joshua Bloch says Java already has closures ( in the form of anonymous inner classes ) After reading what you said, I agree. The problems with a.i.c is they are way to verbose.

Comment: How does one perform type safety with a closure? Surly an abstract anonymous class is clearer than a closure?

Answer (score 42):

They don't make an Object-Oriented language better. They make practical languages more practical.

If you're attacking a problem with the OO hammer - represent everything as interactions between objects - then a closure makes no sense. In a class-based OO language, closures are the smoke-filled back rooms where stuff gets done but no one talks about it afterwards. Conceptually, it is abhorrent.

In practice, it's extremely convenient. I don't really want to define a new type of object to hold context, establish the "do stuff" method for it, instantiate it, and populate the context... i just want to tell the compiler, "look, see what i have access to right now? That's the context i want, and here's the code i want to use it for - hold on to this for me 'till i need it".

Fantastic stuff.

Comment: -1: "They don't make an Object-Oriented language better. They make practical languages more practical.": I strongly disagree with this principle. Maybe closures will make Java more practical, but in principle one should not sacrifice the coherence of a language just to make it "more practical". IMO there must be another, stronger motivation for introducing closures. A language that has a very heterogeneous semantics and a lot of special cases just to be "more practical" is more difficult to learn. Programming languages should be based on concepts not on idioms.

Answer (score 37):

The most obvious thing would be a pseudo-replacement for all those classes that just have a single method called run() or actionPerformed() or something like that.  So instead of creating a Thread with a Runnable embedded, you'd use a closure instead.  Not more powerful than what we've got now, but much more convenient and concise.

So do we *need* closures?  No.  Would they be nice to have?  Sure, as long as they don't feel bolted on, as I fear they would be.

Comment: Thanks for reinforcing my suspicion that closures would just be syntactic sugar for anonymous inner classes.

Comment: If they were as complete as JavaScript/C#/C++0x closures, they would be more powerful than anonymous inner classes, because they would be able to capture modifiable references to local variables, not just readonly copies of finals.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker: You can simulate this by wrapping the modifiable variable in a container object (putting it on the heap) which is then assigned to a local final var.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom - you can indeed, or even better, you can use a language that does this for you! :)

Comment: @Bill: Closures are NOT the same as anonymous functions or inner classes, though the differences are subtle. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Here is a closure implementation for Java 5, 6, and 7

http://mseifed.blogspot.se/2012/09/closure-implementation-for-java-5-6-and.html

It contains all one could ask for... I think it is pretty awesome!

Comment: @jodonnell. I also think that is what you are describing. I don't why this class has never surfaced until now.. 

http://mseifed.blogspot.se/2012/09/closure-implementation-for-java-5-6-and.html

Answer (score 18):

I suppose for supporting core functional programming concepts, you need closures. Makes the code more elegant and composable with the support for [closures](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Closure.html). Also, I like the idea of passing around lines of code as parameters to functions.

Comment: Agreed, just for convenient map/filter implementations it would be worth it. Not to mention most uses of anonymous inner classes. Readability and code size counts.

Answer (score 12):

There are some very useful 'higher order functions' which can do operations on lists using closures. Higher order functions are functions having 'function objects' as parameters.

E.g. it is a very common operation to apply some transformation to every element in a list. This higher order function is commonly called 'map' or 'collect'. (See the *. spread operator of [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators)).

For example to square each element in a list without closures you would probably write:

```
List<Integer> squareInts(List<Integer> is){
   List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(is.size());
   for (Integer i:is)
      result.add(i*i);
   return result;
}
```

Using closures and map and the proposed syntax, you could write it like that:

```
is.map({Integer i => i*i})
```

(There is a possible performance problem here regarding boxing of primitive types.)

As explained by Pop Catalin there is another higher order function called 'select' or 'filter': It can be used to get all the elements in a list complying to some condition. For example:

Instead of:

```
void onlyStringsWithMoreThan4Chars(List<String> strings){
   List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(str.size()); // should be enough
   for (String str:strings)
      if (str.length() > 4) result.add(str);
   return result;
}
```

Instead you could write something like

```
strings.select({String str => str.length() > 4});
```

using the proposal.

You might look at the Groovy syntax, which is an extension of the Java language to support closures right now. See the chapter on collections of the [Groovy User Guide](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections) for more examples what to do with closures.

A remark:

There is perhaps some clarification needed regarding the term 'closure'. What I've shown above are strictly spoken no closures. They are just 'function objects'. 
A closure is everything which can capture - or 'close over' - the (lexical) context of the code surrounding it. In that sense there are closures in Java right now, i.e. anonymous classes:

```
Runnable createStringPrintingRunnable(final String str){
    return new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
          System.out.println(str); // this accesses a variable from an outer scope
       }
    };
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for knowing (and explaining) the distinction between closures and functions as values

Answer (score 8):

Java doesn't need closures, an Object oriented language can do everything a closure does using intermediate objects to store state or do actions (in Java's case inner classes). 
But closures are desirable as a feature because they greatly simplify the code and increase readability and as a consequence the maintainability of the code.

I'm no Java specialist but I'm using  C# 3.5 and closures are one of my favorite features of the language, for example take the following statement as an example:

```
// Example #1 with closures
public IList<Customer> GetFilteredCustomerList(string filter) {
    //Here a closure is created around the filter parameter
    return Customers.Where( c => c.Name.Contains(filter)).ToList();
}
```

now take an equivalent example that doesn't use closures

```
//Example #2 without closures, using just basic OO techniques
public IList<Customer> GetFilteredCustomerList(string filter) {
    return new Customers.Where( new CustomerNameFiltrator(filter));
}
... 
public class CustomerNameFiltrator : IFilter<Customer> {
    private string _filter;
    public  CustomerNameFiltrator(string filter) {
         _filter = filter;
    }
    public bool Filter(Customer customer) {
        return customer.Name.Contains( _filter);
    }
}
```

I know this is C# and not Java but the idea is the same, closures are useful for conciseness, and make code shorter and more readable. Behind the scenes, the closures of C# 3.5 do something that's looks very similar to example #2 meaning the compiler creates a private class behind the scenes and passes the 'filter' parameter to it.

Java doesn't need closures to work, as a developer you don't need them either, but, they are useful and provide benefits so that means that they are desirable in a language that is a production language and one of it's goals is productivity.

Comment: note that the difference is much smaller when you use anonymous classes

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt, note that the difference is much more bigger when you have allot of closures and composition of functions.

Answer (score 8):

> I've been reading a lot lately about the next release of Java possibly supporting closures. I feel like I have a pretty firm grasp on what closures are, but I can't think of a solid example of how they would make an Object-Oriented language "better."

Well, most people who use the term "closure" actually mean "function object", and in this sense, function objects make it possible to write simpler code in certain circumstances such as when you need custom comparators in a sort function.

For example, in Python:

```
def reversecmp(x, y):
   return y - x

a = [4, 2, 5, 9, 11]
a.sort(cmp=reversecmp)
```

This sorts the list a in reverse order by passing the custom comparison functoin reversecmp.  The addition of the lambda operator makes things even more compact:

```
a = [4, 2, 5, 9, 11]
a.sort(cmp=lambda x, y : y - x)
```

Java does not have function objects, so it uses "functor classes" to simulate them.  In Java you do the equivalent operation by implementing a custom version of the Comparator class, and passing that to the sort function:

```
class ReverseComparator implements Comparator {
   public compare(Object x, Object y) {
      return (Integer) y - (Integer) x;
   }

...

List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5, 9, 11);
Collections.sort(a, new ReverseComparator());
```

As you can see, it gives the same effect as closures, but is clumsier and more verbose.  However, the addition of anonymous inner classes obviates most of the pain:

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5, 9, 11);
Comparator reverse = new Comparator() {
   public Compare(Object x, Object y) {
       return (Integer) y - (Integer) x;
   }
}
Collections.sort(a, reverse);
```

So I would say that the combination of functor classes + anonymous inner classes in Java is sufficient to compensate for the lack of true function objects, making their addition unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

Java has had closures since 1.1, just in a very cumbersome and limited way.

They are often useful wherever you have a callback of some description. A common case is to abstract away control flow, leaving the interesting code to call an algoritm with a closure that has no external control flow.

A trivial example is for-each (although Java 1.5 already has that). Whilst you can implement a forEach method in Java as it stands, it's far too verbose to be useful.

An example which already makes sense with existing Java is implementing the "execute around" idiom, whereby resource acquisition and release is abstracted. For instance, file open and close can be done within try/finally, without the client code having to get the details right.

Answer (score 3):

When closures finally arrive in Java, I will gleefully get rid of all my custom comparator classes.

```
myArray.sort( (a, b) => a.myProperty().compareTo(b.myProperty() );
```

...looks a helluva lot better than...

```
myArray.sort(new Comparator<MyClass>() {
   public int compare(MyClass a, MyClass b) {
      return a.myProperty().compareTo(b.myProperty();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A few people have said, or implied, that closures are just syntactic sugar - doing what you could already do with anonymous inner classes and making it more convenient to pass parameters in.

They *are* syntactic sugar in the same sense that Java is syntactic sugar for assembler (that "assembler" could be bytecode, for sake of argument). In other words they raise they level of abstraction, and this is an important concept.

Closures promote the concept of the function-as-object to a first class entity - one that increases the expressiveness of code, rather than cluttering it with even more boilerplate.

An example that's close to my heart has already been mentioned by Tom Hawtin - implementing the Execute Around idiom, which is just about the only way to get RAII into Java. [I wrote a blog entry on exactly that subject](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2009/9/24/raii-and-closures-in-java.html) a couple of years ago when I first heard closures might be coming.

Ironically, I think the very reason that closures would be good for Java (more expressiveness with less code) may be what rattles many Java advocates. Java has a mindset of "spell everything out the long way". That and the fact that closures are a nod towards a more functional way of doing things - which I also see as a Good Thing, but may water down the pure OO message that many in the Java community hold dear.

Comment: I think "spell everything out the long way" would be more accurate as "spell everything out explicitly" (at least in my case).  There is a subtle difference.

Comment: Well - I'd say the two are distinct cases with a large intersection. So perhaps if we talk of the union of those two we get to the knub of it :-)

Comment: First-class functions are a distinct idea from closures. The former refers to treating a reference to a function (or the function itself) as a value -- one that can be passed around and invoked at will. The latter is concerned with capturing references to values available lexically at the point of definition and extending their lifetime through the lifetime of the function created there. One can have first-class functions without having closures, though I don't think the converse makes sense.

Comment: Well, they are distinct ideas, but one is based on the other (hence the lack of transitivity in your final comment). I said that, "Closures *promote* the concept of the function-as-object to a first class entity" - not that they were the same thing. The fact is, as it stands, Java does not have a proper concept of first class functions, but if it got Closures it would get that too as a pre-requisite. That's really what I meant. But if that wasn't clear it's good that you've clarified it with your comment :-)

Comment: When you raise the level of abstraction you are introducing new semantics not just using syntactic sugar. Java is not syntactic sugar over assembly.

Answer (score 3):

I have been thinking a lot about the topic of this **very interesting question** in
the last few days. First of all, if I have understood correctly, Java already has
some basic notion of closures (defined through anonymous classes) but the new feature
that is going to be introduced is the support for closures based on anonymous functions.

This extension will definitely make the language more expressive but I am not sure
if it really fits with the rest of the language.
Java has been designed as an object-oriented language with no support for functional programming: Will the new semantics be easy to understand? Java 6 does not even have functions, will Java 7 have anonymous functions but no "normal" functions?

My impression is that as new programming styles or paradigms like functional
programming become more popular, everyone wants to use them in their
favourite OOP language. This is understandable: one wants to continue to use
a language they're familiar with while adopting new features. But in this way
a language can become really complex and lose coherence.

So my attitude at the moment is to stick to Java 6 for OOP (I hope Java 6 will still
be supported for a while) and, in case I really get interested in doing OOP + FP,
to take a look at some other language like Scala (Scala was defined to be multi-
paradigm from the beginning and can be well integrated with Java) rather than switching
to Java 7.

I think Java owes its success to the fact that it combines a simple language with very
powerful libraries and tools, and I do not think that new features like closures will
make it a better programming language.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but +1 for your suggestions!
Personally, I **do** use Scala, and its functional programming is great.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the vote. Maybe I should have made my statement more explicit: I think that Java does not need closures and that this extension will make the language unnecessarily complex.

Comment: I think you are right about that. I think that Java never had functions as objects because Sun didn't want it like C's function pointers (or so I read in Core Java 2).

However, there **are** ways of implementing functions as objects that do not involve function pointers. Again, Scala is the best example of that.

Comment: I just bought my Scala book, staring to read it and I like it a lot! Definitely, I think one should not fumble around with a language like Java or C++, which were not designed to support FP. Java remains one of my favourite language, but if one wants OOP + FP one should look at a language that was designed for that.

Answer (score 3):

Now that [JDK8](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) is about to be released there is more information available that can enrich the answers to this question.

Bria Goetz, language architect at Oracle, has published a series of papers (yet drafts) on the current state of lambda expressions in Java. It does also cover closures as they are planning to release them in the upcoming JDK, which should be code complete [around January 2013](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) and should be released around midyear 2013.

- [The State of Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html): in the first page or two this article attempts to answer the question presented here. Although I still found it short in arguments, but is is full of examples.
- [The State of Lambda - Libraries Edition](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html): this is also very interesting because it covers advantages like lazy evaluation and parallelism.
- [The Translation of Lambda Expressions](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html): which basically explains the desugaring process done by the Java compiler.

Comment: Lexical scoping and Variable Capture from The State of Lambda are great reads; but "effective final", IMHO, is not such a good idea, the compiler probably needs an extra pass to determine "effective finality" and also code that compiles today starts breaking tomorrow b ecause a newly coded line "miles" away from the closure converted the reference to mutable.

Comment: @UstamanSangat My understanding is that all free variables in a closure, in Java, are effectively final whether you declare them explicitly or not. I have not read the translation strategy in a while, so I do not know if this is just a compiler thing or if it is instrumented in the JVM somehow.

Comment: Agreed, my point was mostly about a new line of code 20 lines away from the closure changing a previously effectively final variable to a mutable one. When that code doesn't compile, a less sophisticated developer might get confused. But I think an IDE can always help.

Answer (score 2):

As a java developer who is trying to teach themselves lisp in an attempt to become a better programmer, I would say that I would like to see the Josh Block proposal for closures implemented.  I find myself using anonymous inner classes to express things like what to do with each element of a list when aggregating some data.  To would be nice to represent that as a closure, instead of having to create an abstract class.

Comment: By "abstract class" you mean aonymous inner class?

Comment: I *think* this is the proposal you're referring to. http://docs.google.com/Doc.aspx?id=k73_1ggr36h

Comment: yes, Tom - I do mean that - sorry

And that looks like it Bill - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Closures in an imperative language (examples: JavaScript, C#, the forthcoming C++ refresh) are not the same as anonymous inner classes. They need to be able to capture modifiable references to local variables. Java's inner classes can only capture local `final` variables.

Almost any language feature can be criticised as non-essential:

- `for`, `while`, `do` are all just syntactic sugar over `goto`/`if`.
- Inner classes are syntactic sugar over classes with a field pointing to the outer class.
- Generics are syntactic sugar over casts.

Exactly the same "non-essential" argument should have blocked the inclusion of all the above features.

Comment: Just to be clear, my question wasn't intended to argue in favor of blocking the inclusion of closures.  Also, I would have agreed with the "non-essential" argument for one of the features you mentioned above. :)

Comment: Many features are not essential. However, IMHO one should look at how often a feature is going to be used compared to the complexity it adds to the language semantics and tools.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Closure Examples](http://www.blog.dannynet.net/archives/87)

Comment: It is the first link return by google search for *java closure example*

Answer (score 0):

Not only that benjismith, but I love how you can just do...

myArray.sort{ it.myProperty }

You only need the more detailed comparator you've shown when the natural language comparison of the property doesn't suit your needs.

I absolutely love this feature.

Answer (score 0):

What about readability and maintainability...one-liner closures are harder to understand and debug, imo
Software has looong life and you can get people with rudimentary knowledge of the language to maintain it...So spread out logic better than one-liners for easy maintenance...You generally don't have a software star looking after software after its release...

Comment: Are you speaking from experience?  My experience has been exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Groovy, a language that's mostly compatible with Java, and runs on the JRE, but supports Closures.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of binding in anonymous function [i.e. if the variables (and method arguments if there is an enclosing method) of the outer context are declared **final** then they are available but not otherwise], I don't quite understand what that restriction actually buys.

I use "final" profusely anyways. So, if my intent was to use the same objects inside the closure, I would indeed declare those objects final in the enclosing scope. But what would be wrong in letting the "closure [java a.i.c.]" just get a copy of the reference as if passed via a constructor (well that in fact is how it is done).

If the closure wants to overwrite the reference, so be it; it will do so without changing the copy that the enclosing scope sees.

If we argue that that would lead to unreadable code (e.g. maybe it's not straight-forward to see what the object reference is at the time of the constructor call for the a.i.c.), then how about at least making the syntax less verbose? Scala? Groovy?

Comment: @Edwin Dolarzo's links are great to read. Need to know what approach are already taken by Scala and Groovy and others